# Différences entre « référer » et « se référer »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Nonobstant [ces réponses](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1757074#post14453235), pourriez-vous SVP énoncer les différences ? je ne les perçois pas.

Les définitions de [*référer*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rer/67449?q=referer#66691) 
et [*se référer*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rer/67450?q=referer#66692) contiennent toutes les deux

> Se rapporter à quelque chose :

Answer (score 1):

Dans le cas qui t'intéresse il s'agit d'un emploi linguistique. Définition B. 3. extraite du TLF :

> Avoir pour référent. *On ne dit plus comme naguère qu'un mot nomme ou signifie une chose, on dit qu'un mot réfère à une chose* (*D. D. L.1976*, *s.v. référence*).

Concernant l'emploi pronominal, quelqu'un *se réfère* à quelque chose lorsqu'il s'appuie lui-même sur cette chose pour ses propres besoins (par exemple, argumenter ses propos). Selon le TLF :

> Se rapporter à (quelque chose) qui l'explique, le précède, l'inspire.

ou

> Se tourner vers (quelqu'un, quelque chose) qui représente la source, l'origine, l'autorité sur laquelle on s'appuie, on se fonde

D'autres subtilités (y compris l'emploi de *en référer à*) sont illustrées [dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rer).